# Sorting partially missing arrays with jmespath

Tags: jmespath

I am trying to sort this source data `outeractivities` by `outer_name` and, then, `activities` by and `inner_name`:

*Sourcedata.json*:

```json
[
    {
        "outeractivities": [
            {
                "outer_name": "2"
            },
            {
                "outer_name": "1",
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "inner_name": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "inner_name": "A"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected output:

```json
[
    {
        "outeractivities": [
            {
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "inner_name": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "inner_name": "B"
                    }
                ],
                "outer_name": "1"
            },
            {
                "outer_name": "2"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

By using

```sh
cat Sourcedata.json | jp "[].{outeractivities:sort_by(outeractivities[]. \
{outer_name:outer_name, activities:sort_by(activities[].{inner_name:inner_name},&inner_name) \
},&outer_name)  \
}"
```

I will get the exception:

> ```
> Error evaluating JMESPath expression: Invalid type for: <nil>, expected: []jmespath.jpType{"array"}
> ```

If I change

```json
{
          "outer_name": "2"
}
```

to

```json
{
          "outer_name": "2",
          "activities": []
}
```

It does work.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the error is occurring due to the fact that `sort_by` is failing to process properly when the property to sort on does not exists, what you could do is to make a list of two lists:

- one with all the `outeractivities` having the `activities` property, sorted on this field
- one with all the `outeractivities` that does not have the `activities` property

And, then, [flatten](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections) those two lists.

Given the query:

```
[].{ 
  outeractivities: sort_by(
    [
      outeractivities[?activities == null], 
      outeractivities[?activities != null].{ 
        outer_name: outer_name, 
        activities: sort_by(activities, &inner_name)
      }
    ] [], 
    &outer_name
  )
}
```

This yields the expected:

```json
[
  {
    "outeractivities": [
      {
        "outer_name": "1",
        "activities": [
          {
            "inner_name": "A"
          },
          {
            "inner_name": "B"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "outer_name": "2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```